# Need to save list after inline editing

Tags: list, inlineeditsupport

I have a Visualforce page that shows some information about a User's Tasks. The User wants the ability to edit some of the information straight from this page without having to actually go into the "Edit" page for a designated Task. I've setup something that does this, but cannot seem to get the information to save and haven't really found much in the way of telling me how to do this. If someone could help me at least understand what I need to do that would be hugely helpful. My code will be posted below this. I also use a pagination add-on package called "PageBlockTableEnhancerADV" as well.

Visualforce Page Code:

```
<apex:page controller="TaskListController1">

<style>
    .pbHeader {
        font-size: 110%;
    }
    .activeButton {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
</style>      

<apex:form >
    <c:PageBlockTableEnhancerADV targetPbTableIds="pbt"  pageSizeOptions="5,10,15,30,1000" defaultPageSize="1000" enableExport="false"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Tasks">
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!tasks}" var="t" id="pbt" >
             <apex:column >
                 <apex:outputLink title="" value="/{!t.id}/e?retURL=/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}" style="font-weight:bold">Edit</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!DeleteTask}" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" style="font-weight:bold">Del
                     <apex:param value="{!t.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!taskId}" />
                 </apex:commandLink>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Subject" style="{!IF((t.ActivityDate = TODAY()),'background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" >
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!t.id}" target="_blank">{!t.subject}</apex:outputLink>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!t.WhoID}" headerValue="Contact/Lead" style="{!IF((t.ActivityDate = TODAY()),'background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" />
             <apex:column value="{!t.WhatID}" headerValue="Name" style="{!IF((t.ActivityDate = TODAY()),'background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" />
             <apex:column value="{!t.AccountID}" headerValue="Client Name" style="{!IF((t.ActivityDate = TODAY()),'background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" />
             <apex:column value="{!t.ActivityDate}" headervalue="Due Date" style="{!IF((t.ActivityDate = TODAY()),'background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" />
                <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                    hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                    changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
             <apex:column value="{!t.Status}" headerValue="Status" style="{!IF((t.ActivityDate = TODAY()),'background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" />
                <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                    hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                    changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
             <apex:column value="{!t.Priority}" headerValue="Priority" style="{!IF((t.ActivityDate = TODAY()),'background:rgb(243, 171, 171);', '')}" />
         </apex:pageblockTable>                       
         <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
             <apex:commandButton title="New Task" value="New Task" onclick="window.open('/00T/e?')"/>
             <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
             <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>      
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex Class Code:

```
public class TaskListController1
    {   
    private integer list_limit = 1000; //sets the number of tasks loaded
    Date today = Date.today();
    ID userid = UserInfo.getUserId();

    public List<Task> tasks { get; set; }

    public Id taskId {get; set;}
    public List<Task> tasksToDel { get; set; }

    public TaskListController1() {
         //load account data into our DataTable
         LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        tasks = [SELECT Id, Subject, Status, ActivityDate, WhoID, WhatID, Description, isClosed, OwnerID, AccountID, Priority FROM Task 
             WHERE isClosed = FALSE AND OwnerID =: userid
             ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC 
             LIMIT : list_limit ];
    }

    public void DeleteTask() {
       tasksToDel = [SELECT Id, Subject, Status, ActivityDate, WhoID, WhatID, Description, isClosed, OwnerID FROM Task 
             WHERE Id = :taskId];
       if(tasksToDel.size() > 0 || tasksToDel[0].Id != '')
       {
           delete tasksToDel;
       }
       LoadData();
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            UPDATE tasks;
            LoadData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference edit() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're facing? You say you can't get the information to save - is an error being throw, are you not seeing the DML updates being reflected in records, etc...in short, what is happening as is?

Comment: @BrianMansfield Sorry about that, I didn't intend for the vague question. The problem is that after changing fields that have inline editing and pressing the "Save" button, upon reloading the page, none of the information is actually changed. For example, if I changed the Status to Completed and then hit Save, nothing is changed when the page refreshes. Getting the "save()" method in the Apex class to work on the whole list of loaded Tasks is essentially where I'm getting stumped. The code is far from streamlined and I'm an amateur with Apex/Visualforce but I hope that clarifies a bit!

Comment: I notice that your Visualforce is missing the `<apex:pageMessages/>` that would display any errors occurring in your `save` method, including those that end up in the `catch` of your `try`/`catch`. Adding the `<apex:pageMessages/>` should help you make progress.